# How to process unstructured Text File using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking to process text file using `Spark RDD` which has data like below:

```
----------------------------*-----------------------

   state:xx             sub:z    |Basic info

company:abc        rate:123      |

----------------------------*------------------------

                     Date: 12-03-2019
```

I am expecting data to be in below format:

```
State:XX
Sub:z
Company:abc
rate:123
Date:12-03-2019
```

When I tried to remove special characters '-' using `data1=data.ReplaceAll('-',"")` function, it is removing - even from date also,i.e 12032019, But date should be in 12-03-2019 and also I am not getting how to move `sub:z ,company:abc andrate:123` to new lines.Please help

Comment: with more details people can help you more.what's the whole file looks like? how many records may it have?

Comment: zhang-yuan Thanks for your response .It is around 600 pages big file it also has data in different format .it is starting piece of data mentioned above.where I am looking for initial solution

Answer (score 1):

without providing further details, here are my suggestions:

1. just remove lines start with `-`, you may get something like this

```
state:xx sub:z |Basic info
company:abc rate:123 |
Date: 12-03-2019
```

2. then remove data afeter `|`

```
state:xx sub:z
company:abc rate:123
Date: 12-03-2019
```

3. replace the (blank space) with `\n\r`

   > not sure whether `Date:` has a blank space behind
   >
   > if so, you can replace that `'Date: '` to `'Date:'` first

```
state:xx
sub:z
company:abc
rate:123
Date:12-03-2019
```

hope this would help